# how to store arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, storage, local-storage, indexeddb

I want to be able to store an array in JavaScript locally for use offline, etc such as in indexedDB and localStorage. However, I understand that localStorage only stores strings and indexedDB only stores objects. I know that I could just JSON serialize the array and store it in localStorage, but I am wondering if there is some more official way to do it.

Comment: I think serializing as JSON *is* the official way to do this.

Comment: is there any way to do it in indexedDB? localStorage with JSON will work, but indexedDB may be more convenient.

Comment: As far as I know, IndexedDB is a key/value pair database, where the value can be [any object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB).  Maybe try putting an array as a value and see what happens?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can tell you indexedDB is a lot faster then the localStorage and can store a larger amout of data (localstorage = max 5MB), but indexedDB has less support... Btw in the indexedDB you have 2 solutions. You can store the array as an object in an objectstore, or store alle the items in the array individual as object in the object store

Comment: I want to store it as an object in a object store. localStorage is fine, but indexedDB is better for this specific situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you pretty much stringify and parse from localStorage.  I use this helper..

```
var _localStorage = {};

_localStorage.set = function(n, o){
  localStorage.setItem(n, JSON.stringify(o||{}));
}

_localStorage.get = function(n){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(n));
}

_localStorage.array = function(n, f, p){
    var arr = _localStorage.get(n) || [];
    arr[f](p); _localStorage.set(n, arr);
}

// test

_localStorage.set('cfg', {name:'pro'});
console.log(_localStorage.get('cfg'));

_localStorage.set('cfg', [{name:'pro'}]);
_localStorage.array('cfg', 'push', {name:'flav'});
console.log(_localStorage.get('cfg'));
```

Comment: What if not all of the items in localStorage are arrays?

Comment: You can use .get() and .set() on objects or arrays.  .array() is just a helper function, so if you're storing an array so you can do this..  _localStorage.set('cfg', [{name:'pro'}]);
_localStorage.array('cfg', 'push', {name:'flav'});   -- instead of having to do this --  var arr = _localStorage.get('cfg'); arr.push({name:'flav'}); _localStorage.set('cfg', arr);

Answer (score 1):

You are right about using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) to serialize it and store it in [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

To store it:

```
localStorage['foo'] = JSON.stringify(foo);
```

And to retrieve it:

```
var foo = JSON.parse(localStorage['foo']);
```

I assume you are aware that this will not work in older browsers (i.e. Internet Explorer 6/7).

Comment: but to modify it I cannot use localStorage['foo'].push('hello') and things like that, correct? I would have to get it from localStorage, parse it, modify it, stringify it, and then add it to localStorage again. This is fine, but I would prefer something else.

Comment: @Markasoftware I really don't know, but I _guess_ that you can't do that. You'll probably have to retrieve it, parse JSON, modify it, serialize it in JSON again and then store it. I may be wrong here though.

Comment: localStorage is not supported in IE6/7 anyway so JSON in those browsers will not be necessary

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten that! I guess there's no way of supporting IE 6/7 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by something like HTML5 Offline Storage: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Concerning the way to "serialize" objects in Javascript, you can achieve that by simply keeping the JSON formalism used by Javascript Objects.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said, it looks like JSON with localStorage is the way to do this. However, this looks like the best way to do it:

```
_localStorage={
    getItem: function(key){
        var value=localStorage.getItem(key);
        try{
            unJSON=JSON.parse(value);
            return unJSON;
        }
        catch(e){
            return value;
        }
    },
    setItem: function(key,value){
        if(typeof value!=='string'){
            var JSONned=JSON.stringify(value)
            localStorage.setItem(key,JSONned);
        }
        else{
            localStorage.setItem(key,value);
        }
    }
}
```